# point the drawable from another application in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

I need to set the ic_launcher_browser icon from the Browser Application in my package for a particular Activity in AndroidManifest.xml (android:icon="")

How do i do that??

Like android:icon="@android:drawable/xyz"

Can't we specify android:icon="@packagename:drawable/xyz"

Regards,
Sanat